# Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError) with rails 2.3.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am  having ruby version *ruby-1.9.3-p547 [ x86_64 ]* which i am using for *Rails 3.0*.
Now i am having a project with rails version *'2.3.18'*. When I entered teh project through command promt, it asked to install **rvm use ree-1.8.7-2012.02** [ x86_64 ].
When i run bundle install, i am getting the following error:

```
[root@raj community]# bundle install
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1208:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22
    from /usr/local/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15
```

Please help me out.

My Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '2.3.18'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '2.0.4'
gem 'acts_as_archive', '0.4.0'
gem 'acts_as_dropdown', '2.0.3'
gem 'also_migrate', '0.3.5'
gem 'axlsx', '1.3.5'
gem 'bitly', '0.5.1'
gem 'builder', '3.0.0'
gem 'capistrano', '2.5.18'
gem 'capistrano-ext', '1.2.1'
gem 'chronic', '0.3.0'
gem 'command-t', '1.2.1'
gem 'daemons', '1.0.10'
gem 'database_cleaner', '0.6.0'
gem 'diff-lcs', '1.1.2'
gem 'eventmachine', '0.12.10'
gem 'github-markup', '0.5.3'
gem 'hashie', '0.2.0'
gem 'hoe', '2.5.0'
gem 'hoptoad_notifier', '2.4.2'
gem 'htmlentities', '4.3.1'
gem 'httparty', '0.5.2'
gem 'i18n', '0.6.0'
gem 'json_pure', '1.4.6'
gem 'mail', '2.3.0'
gem 'memcache-client', '1.8.5'
# gem 'memcached', '0.19.7'
gem 'mime-types', '1.16'
gem 'mocha', '0.9.10'
gem 'mogli', '0.0.16'
gem 'money', '2.1.5'
gem 'mover', '0.3.6'
gem 'oauth', '0.4.7'
gem 'polyglot', '0.3.1'
gem 'pony', '1.3'
gem 'powder', '0.1.7'
gem 'prawn', '0.8.4'
gem 'prawn-core', '0.8.4'
gem 'prawn-layout', '0.8.4'
gem 'prawn-security', '0.8.4'
gem 'rack', '1.1.6'
gem 'rack-rewrite', '1.0.2'
gem 'rack-test', '0.5.6'
# gem 'rmagick', '2.13.1'
gem 'rspec', '1.3.1'
gem 'rspec-rails', '1.3.3'
gem 'ruby-hmac', '0.4.0'
gem 'rubyzip', '0.9.9'
gem 'rvm', '1.11.3.5'
gem 'thor', '0.14.6'
gem 'tzinfo', '0.3.16'
gem 'validatable', '1.6.7'
gem 'webrat', '0.7.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '2.2.2'
gem 'xml-simple', '1.0.12'
gem 'yajl-ruby', '0.7.8'
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
```

Comment: @RAJ - added Gemfile

Comment: Try to execute "gem install bundler"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install `bundler`. Here are some words from [RVM official website](https://rvm.io/integration/bundler):

> Starting with 1.11.0 new RVM installations has bundler enabled by default, you can still install it.

Try installing `rubygems-bunder` with:

```
gem install rubygems-bundler
```

Now, to make all the executables bundler compatible, run:

```
gem regenerate_binstubs
```

Comment: step 1 results in `You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory`