# Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 0 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby, bundler, gitlab

I'm trying to install gitlab on my vhost. It's an Ubuntu 14.04.

The introduction tells me to run the command:

```
sudo -u gitlab -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws kerberos
```

But than I always get the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 0 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/gitlab/.gem/ruby/2.2.0:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

If I start bundle as root it works normally.

I tried a lot of solutions provided in other threads like:

[“Could not find bundler” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166081/could-not-find-bundler-error)
or 
[Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError) with rails 2.3.18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626468/could-not-find-bundler-0-amongst-gemloaderror-with-rails-2-3-18)

and so on but nothing resloves this error. 
Now I have no idea what I could do.

My system:

- Ubuntu 14.04 (x_64)
- bundler 1.11.2
- ruby 2.2.4p230

I hope you can help me out.

If you need any other information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very simple problem with rights.

Look if /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0 is accessible by others than root.

If not do :

```
chmod o+x /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/
```

Maybe the path isn't accessible a folder up or down, so change permissions there.

You can look for permissions with

```
ll YOUR_PATH
```