# Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [bundler-unload-1.0.2, executable-hooks-1.3.2, gem-wrappers-1.2.7, json-1.8.1 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on Rails 2.3.2 application. I installed Ruby 1.8.6 using RVM. When I tried to run `bundler -v` or `rails -v` etc, I am getting a error as:

```
venky@indeg:~/Desktop/practice/AppMonitor$ sudo gem install -v=2.3.2 rails
Successfully installed rails-2.3.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-2.3.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-2.3.2...
venky@indeg:~/Desktop/practice/AppMonitor$ rails -v
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [bundler-unload-1.0.2, executable-hooks-1.3.2, gem-wrappers-1.2.7, json-1.8.1, rubygems-bundler-1.4.4, rvm-1.11.3.9] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

this is my rvm ruby version :

```
venky@indeg:~/Desktop/practice/AppMonitor$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.8.6-p420 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-head [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.1-p431 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ i686 ]
 * ruby-2.2.1 [ i686 ]
   ruby-2.2.3 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I tried some of the links like [Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError) with rails 2.3.18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626468/could-not-find-bundler-0-amongst-gemloaderror-with-rails-2-3-18) and [Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278047/could-not-find-rails-0-amongst-gemloaderror), but didn't helped me.
Please help me to get out of this..

Comment: okay i got your problem what is the version of ruby

Comment: I am using ruby 1.8.6

Comment: rvm use ruby 1.8.6 try this

Comment: I am already using ruby 1.8.6.

Comment: then try that and run bundle install if it doesn't work then do rvm list

Comment: when I run bundle install also, I am getting the same error,

Comment: okay and what is the result you are getting after rvm list

Comment: did you try that command  
rvm use ruby 1.8.6  .I am specifically saying because sometimes ruby behave weird and also tell me the result of rvm list

Comment: added to my question. please check

Comment: okay i got it try with rvm use ruby version 1.9.1 and then run bundle install

Comment: I am facing rake issue in 1.9.1, with 1.9.3 it's working fine. Can I continue with this version?

Comment: yeah absolutely ....it will work fine and I am giving an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to do  `rvm list` and then   `rvm use ruby version`